# SQL query with an OR clause and only one parameter

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I was wondering if is there a way to do a query like this one (where `Z` is a variable)

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.X = Z OR t.Y = Z
```

writing only one time the `Z`. To be more specific I would like to do the same query like so

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE (t.X OR t.Y) = Z
```

I am using an Oracle DB and it (obviously) gives me an error when I try to execute it BUT I really like a way to do it like in the second query.

To make you know my situation `X` and `Y` are both *VARCHAR2* and I already try something like

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE (t.X || t.Y) like '%Z%'
```

But, unluckily, it is not as accurate as the first one.

Comment: Please check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/select.html and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/expressions.html syntax descriptions. Your first SQL statement is fine, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Because I'm maintaining a Java application and in this specific case I prefer to change only the query instead of add more code lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `in`:

```
WHERE Z IN (t.X, t.Y)
```

Columns can be in the `IN` list as well as constants.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: This is a solution I would have never thought of, I didn't know that columns can be on the right side of an IN, thank you :)

Comment: @GiacomoF.M. . . . I remember a long, long time ago, I had the same reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE (t.X like %Z% OR t.Y  like %Z% )
```

Comment: I thank you for the answer but doing it like you say force me to write 2 times the same variable